# Using Cytoscape.JS to generate a graph without a front end for a Rest API

Tags: node.js, cytoscape.js

So I am trying to make a Rest API using NodeJS where one of its endpoint can output an image of a social network dataset graph that has gone through markov clustering. All that with the help of the Cytoscape.JS library.

The thing is, I will only be doing this on backend, while the function for exporting the graph as an image requires the graph to not be headless. So I tried using a jsdom for it, but that somehow caught an error too.

```
import cytoscape from "cytoscape";
import { readCsv } from "../Helpers/ReadCsv.js";
import { getEles } from "../Helpers/GetEles.js";
import { stringify } from 'flatted';

const body = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", `<div id="cy" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;"></div>`);
Object.defineProperty(window.HTMLHtmlElement.prototype, 'clientWidth', {value: 1920});
Object.defineProperty(window.HTMLHtmlElement.prototype, 'clientHeight', {value: 1080});
Object.defineProperty(document.getElementById('cy'), 'offsetWidth', {value: 1920});
Object.defineProperty(document.getElementById('cy'), 'offsetHeight', {value: 1080});

export async function cytoGraph(params) {
    //Initialize Cytoscape
    let cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById("cy"),
        fit: true,
        padding: 30,
        centerGraph: true,
    });
    //Read CSV file as JSON data
    const data = await readCsv("data.csv");

    //Convert JSON data into array
    const eles = getEles(data);

    //Add the data array into cytoscape graph
    cy.add(eles);

    //Perform Markov clustering to cytoscape graph
    const markov = cy.elements().markovClustering();

    //export image
    return cy.png();
}
```

This is the error I get if I tried doing it without a header:

```
throw new Error('A headless instance can not render images');
        ^

Error: A headless instance can not render images
```

And this is the error if I tried using the jsdom head:

```
  if (bb.h === 0 || bb.w === 0) {
         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'h')
```

TL;DR: How would one export a cytoscape export image function in Node instance instead of a browser instance

Answer (score 0):

I didnt use it but you could try https://github.com/cytoscape/cytosnap

"Render graphs on the server side with Cytoscape.js, getting image files as output. This package uses Puppeteer to generate the output. Refer to the Puppeteer documentation to ensure that your machine is configured properly to run Chrome headlessly."

Comment: I have tried it. Do you know if there is a way to generate markov clustering graphs using cytosnap?

Comment: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-markov-cluster/blob/master/demo.html

Maybe you could fork Cytosnap, and pass an option to the `shot` method to  run on the elements

Maybe after line 199 of "cytosnap/index.js"